# Cypress is not detecting route from cy.route()

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I do have backend ready. But i wish that my front end while testing use mock server only which we can create in cypress. My test is

```
        cy.server()
        cy.route({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/dashboard/v1/public/login',
        status:404,
        response:{
                "error": true,
                "message": "User with above credentials does not exists"
            }
        })

        cy.get('[data-testid="loging-page-email-input')
        .type('test@gmail.com')


        cy.get('[data-testid="loging-page-password-input')
        .type('test123')


        cy.get('[data-testid="loging-page-button-clicked')
            .type('{enter}')

        cy.get('[data-testid="loging-page-auth-error-msg') // Here it should grab alert box
```

But the problem is that same credentials are correct if we want to login to website physically. So if cypress is able to login it then we can see that it is not taking data that we are providing in

```
cy.route({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/dashboard/v1/public/login',
        status:404,
        response:{
                "error": true,
                "message": "User with above credentials does not exists"
            }
        })
```

Instead it is making api call and is able to login.

Any idea whats going wrong ? More over my base url is `http://localhost:3000` but my full login api url is `y.x.in/dashboard/v1/public/login`

---

**UPDATE**
I now gave body to route too

```
            cy.server()
            cy.route({
                method:'POST',
                url:'/dashboard/v1/public/login',
                body:{
                    email:"s@gmail.com",
                    password:"sss"
                },
                status:404,
                response:{
                    "error": true,
                    "message": "User with above credentials does not exists"
                }
            })
```

---

[image]
I just checked that after clicking on login button cypress is not catching login api call

Comment: In your route I really miss the API call POST params, I mean, username and password params. Once you added the params in Cypress route, everything should be working fine. You have to simulate the API call with exact the same params, otherwise Cypress is not going to intercept your API call.

Comment: @amolinaalvarez Hey this is how to do that ? I have given body as you said but still it is calling to the remote server. These are the same values of email,password with which i am making api call. But still no results

Comment: let me write an answer, it will be easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, please notice that `method`, `url` and `response` are out of the `options` param.

```
cy.server()
cy.route({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/dashboard/v1/public/login',
    response: {
        "error": true,
        "message": "User with above credentials does not exists"
    },
    status:404,
    options: {
        body:{
            email:"s@gmail.com",
            password:"sss"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey I have updated my question. This is login api call and all other apis which i did not defined anywhere in my route are logging here + i removed the login cy.route even then login api is not appearing. Is this helpful for you ?

Comment: that is really weird, could you replace cy.get('[data-testid="loging-page-button-clicked').type('{enter}') with cy.get('[data-testid="loging-page-button-clicked').click() and try again?

Comment: I tried that way too. But Same results I think this may be the bug bcoz it is catching other apis but not the login one

Comment: could you check that the real api call is done from the network tab in the browser?

Comment: Really thankyou man. I was checking that and i found that api was giving CORS for some reason i resolved that and now it is working fine. Really thankyou

Comment: And one more thing. When i take `status:404` out of option then it is working fine. So kindly please check and take it outside of option so to help others